# Getting error while running pip3 install smtp

Tags: python, android, pip, termux, termux-linux

I was trying to operate a toll but when I was listing all the commands so there is a command I.e. `pip3 install smtp`
and I got an error I.e.

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement smtp (from versions: none)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for smtp

Can anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please Don't Write Your Text Like This. It Is Very Annoying To Read Text Where Every Word Is Capitalized

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a package called `smtp` in [python package index (PyPI)](https://pypi.org/). Maybe you meant to use `smtpemail`, `secure-smtplib` or `smtplibaio`? That, or you're missing a dependency.